# Time-Varying Coefficients within R bsts package

Tags: r, time-series

I've been working through using R's bsts package and in the documentation it refers to being able to incorporate time-varying coefficients in the model.

"If predictor variables are present, the regression coefficients are fixed (as opposed to time varying, though time varying coefficients might be added as state component)".

Has anyone been successful at adding time varying coefficients in the state component?